# React how to make validationSchema reusable

Tags: reactjs, validation, formik

i have a component in which i have a form and validationSchema (i use formik).

My validation schema use react-intl to be able to translate messages. Unfortunately i have the same schema in two different places and i want to export it to import in another place also. 
I don't know how to do it because of intl.

My code:

```
import { injectIntl, intlShape } from 'react-intl';

const MyComponent = (props) => {

const { intl } = props;

const setValidationSchema = () => ({
  companyName: string(),
  firstName: string().required(),
  lastName: string().required(),
  dateOfBirth: date().required().typeError(intl.formatMessage(messages.dateOfBirth)),
  street: string().required(),
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like:

`export const MyComponent =(props) =>(
)`
and pass the reference of `intl` as a parameter in the schema

I hope that helps you